# Bean Validation: Receive EntityNotFoundException though have a constraint to validate entity

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator, bean-validation

Technologies: Spring, Hibernate, JSR-303, JQuery
Platform: Windows
I am trying to implement @IdMustExist JSR-303 constraint. The purpose of the constraint is to check whether the entered id value exists in associated table. Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774954/javax-validation-receive-an-error-no-validator-could-be-found-for-type) for the IdMustExist.java and IdMustExistValidator.java code snippets.

Scenario 1 - Valid Id value is entered: In this case, when hibernate's EntityManager.merge operation is executed, I see that the @IdMustExist constraint is executed. It successfully validates that the entered Id value exists in another associated/linked table. Hibernate completes the save operation successfully. I noticed that hibernate fires select SQL for the entity before calling the validator for @IdMustExist.

Scenario 2 - Invalid Id value is entered: In this case, when hibernate's EntityManager.merge operation is executed, it throws EntityNotFoundException (stack trace given below) as it could not find the entity for the entered invalid Id. I was hoping that the constraint @IdMustExist gets fired in the pre-update stage and we can gracefully show error message to the user. But it looks like something fails before hibernate can enter pre-update stage. I see that hibernate fires select SQLs for the entity and then throws the EntityNotFoundException. It does not get a chance to call validate @IdMustExist.

Does it mean, I cannot validate whether the entered Id exists in associated/linked table through JSR-303? Any alternatives?

Thanks for your help in advance.
JP

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.mycompany.myapp.domain.package1.Class1 with id 100
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration$Ejb3EntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(Ejb3Configuration.java:133)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:233)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1080)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1028)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:623)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:291)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.replace(TypeFactory.java:532)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:495)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:423)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:234)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:859)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:843)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:847)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:682)
at com.mycompany.myapp.dao.hibernate.package2.HibernateClass2Dao.save(HibernateClass2Dao.java:101)
at com.mycompany.myapp.service.package2.Class1ServiceImpl.update(Class1ServiceImpl.java:56)
    ...
    ...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

**HibernateClass2Dao.java**

```
    public void save(GenericRequest request, GenericResponse response){
    Class2 class2Request = (Class2) request.getObject(Class2.class.getName());
    EntityManager em = PersistenceUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    Class2 class2Persisted = em.find(Class2.class, class2Request.getId());
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        class2Persisted.setClass1(class2Request.getClass1());
        em.merge(class2Request);
        tx.commit();            
    } catch (RollbackException rbe) {
        response.setSuccess(false);
        rbe.getCause().printStackTrace();
        ConstraintViolationException cve = (ConstraintViolationException) rbe.getCause();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> constraintViolations = cve.getConstraintViolations();
        if (constraintViolations.size() > 0){
            for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : constraintViolations){
                Iterator<Node> itr = violation.getPropertyPath().iterator();
                String propertyPath = itr.next().getName();
                Class<? extends Payload> payload = violation.getConstraintDescriptor().getPayload().iterator().next();
                String payloadName = payload.getCanonicalName();                
                response.addMessage(violation.getMessage(), violation.getLeafBean().getClass().getName(),
                        propertyPath , payloadName);            
            }
        }
    } finally {
        em.close();         
    }
}
```

**Class2ServiceImpl.java**

```
    public void update(GenericRequest request, GenericResponse response){
    class2Dao.save(request, response);
}
```

**Class2Controller.java**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/update")
public @ResponseBody GenericResponse update(String jqGridId, String oper
            , Class2 class2
            , BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {
    GenericResponse response = new GenericResponse(true);
    response.setMessageSource(messageSource);
    Locale locale = new Locale(CommonConstants.DEFAULT_LOCALE);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        response.setSuccess(false);
        addBindingMessages(response, bindingResult, locale);
        return response;
    }
    class2.setId(Long.parseLong(jqGridId));
    class2.setCode(jqGridId);
    GenericRequest request = new GenericRequest(UserUtil.getUser(), class2);
    this.class2Service.update(request, response);
    return response;        
}
```

Comment: @IdMustExist executes a select query right. Will it not throw entity not found exception when the id is not available. The only graceful way I see is have a try catch block around the select query ( For NoEntityFoundException). Its not a checked exception, but you could handle exit condition gracefully.

Comment: The exception is not thrown by @IdMustExist. I have debug statements in @IdMustExist.isValid method but they are not displayed. The exception is thrown by Hibernate some how before @IdMustExist gets a chance to validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your referenced link doesn't shows the code for the DAO, but I assume you are using the `load()` method from the Session. See the javadoc:

> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, assuming that the instance exists.

Note the part that it says "assuming that the instance exists.". Means, you *know* that some entity exists, and you are asking Hibernate to load it. If it doesn't exists, this assumption is broken, and an exception is thrown.

What you may want is to use the `get()` method instead. See what the javadoc says:

> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, or null if there is no such persistent instance.

So, the solution is to change from `load()` to `get()`.

Javadoc: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html

Comment: Thanks! for reply. I have updated the code snippet for HibernateClass2DAO, Class2ServiceImpl and Class2Controller classes in the main question above. Please review. I am not calling load method. The Class2 instance is a new object created by spring to bind request parameter. I am only calling EntityManager.merge() method. I guess hibernate in turn is calling load method.  Please see the EntityNotFound exception stack trace that has call to methods entityIsDetached(), fireLoad() methods etc. Is there a way I can suppress hibernate not to load the associated object? Any other design option?

Comment: I think you hit a grey area from the specification. I had to read the JSR to see if it covered this part, and it seems it doesn't, specially considering that you are setting the ID for the object. In general, I would say that if you have a property marked as "@Id", and this field is populated, the "merge" would assume that this entity exists. The fact that it doesn't is an exception to it's assumption. Would you please try to reproduce this without setting the @Id? As per my understanding of the spec, I'd say that it should not throw any exceptions, but persist this new entity to the database

Comment: But anyway, *my* understanding is that Hibernate is doing the right thing. So, I would perform two operations: 1) issue a "get" (or a query) for an entity with the given ID. 2) perform the merge operation, if it exists.

Comment: Thanks! Partenon. I would try your suggestion and confirm. I think it should work. I do know that Class2 entity exist and hence the Id being set is ok. But Class1 referred in Class2 does not exist. The exception thrown is for class1.

Comment: You were right! Please see modified HibernateClass2Dao.java source code above. I retrieve Class2 first and manually set Class2.setClass1. Then I call em.merge(). I do not get the EntityNotFound exception anymore and my @IdMustExist constraint gets executed that throws ConstraintViolation exception, as expected. Thanks! again. I have another related question that I am creating a new post for.

Answer (score 0):

Several things here. What *Session* is your *CommonDao* using. Really this should be a new session opened on the current connection. The whole issue around using a session (or entity manager within a constraint validator) is discussed on the Hibernate Validator wiki: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/AccessingtheHibernateSessionwithinaConstraintValidator

I wound not recommend this approach though. I would just call *merge* and deal with the Hibernate Core (or JPA) exceptions.